# DynamoDB doesn't save my item

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

My items doesn't get saved when I both have 'Hash' and 'Range' -keytypes in my table. It works if I only have the hash.

My table is defined in my serverless.template file

```
"TestTable" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties" : {
        "TableName" : "Test",
        "AttributeDefinitions" : [
          {"AttributeName" : "UserId", "AttributeType" : "S"},
          {"AttributeName" : "Id", "AttributeType" : "N"}
        ],
        "KeySchema"            : [
          {"AttributeName" : "UserId", "KeyType" : "HASH"},
          {"AttributeName" : "Id", "KeyType" : "RANGE"}

        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput" : {
          "ReadCapacityUnits" : 3,
          "WriteCapacityUnits" : 3
        }
    }
}
```

My function looks like this:

```
    public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> CreateAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.Id = 1;
        test.UserId = "Test";

        await DDBContext.SaveAsync<Test>(test);

        var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Body = "foo",
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
        };

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What error message do you receive when it doesn't save?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I don't get any error message. Either if I run my test or deployed at AWS. It returns my "foo" body message. However, I don't know if I could see some other messages in the AWS gui?